# How to escape dots in variable using bash, and replacing value in file?

Tags: bash, shell

I'm trying to work out how to edit a file in a bash script, and replace it with a variable with the dots escaped. For example `123.123.123.123` needs to be replaced in the file **jail.local**, as `123\.123\.123\.123`. I found some posts on SO that gave me some ideas, but I just can't get it right:

```
#!/bin/bash

admin_host="admin.foo.com"

server_ip_4=$(hostname -I | awk '{print $1}')
server_ip_4_escaped=$(hostname -I | awk '{print $1}' | sed "s/\./\\\./g")

echo "TEST: $server_ip_4_escaped , $server_ip_4"

sed -i "s/IP_v4/$(echo $server_ip_4_escaped)/" /etc/fail2ban/filter.d/maltrail.conf
```

prints out:

```
sh install-maltrail.sh
Please type your admin URL - i.e admin.foobar.com and press [ENTER]
TEST: 213\.219\.38\.123 , 213.219.38.123
```

But when I look at maltrail.conf, it has:

```
failregex = ^.*admin.foo.com <HOST> \d+ 213.219.38.44 .*(attacker|scanner|reputation).*
```

when I need:

```
failregex = ^.*admin\.foo\.com <HOST> \d+ 213\.219\.38\.44 .*(attacker|scanner|reputation).*
```

Comment: Why not `sed 's/[.]/\\./g' file`?? Add the `-i` option to edit the file in place.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin not sure what you mean? I'm trying to search for `IP_v4` in my file, and replace it with the escaped v4 IP :)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin ah ok I see what you mean. I'm not sure that would work, as I also have 3 instances of `.*` in the file, which I don't want to be escaped

Comment: Okay, so you have more than just the IPs in the file. That will escape the `.` with `\.`, but will do it for EVERY `'.'` in the file....

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin ya - the file has `failregex = ^.*admin\.foo\.com <HOST> \d+ 213\.219\.38\.44 .*(attacker|scanner|reputation).*`

Comment: One messy option I guess would be to do as you suggested, and then right after go in and replace instances of `\.*` with just `.*` - but surely there is a better way

Comment: This should work `sed 's/[.]\([0-9]\{1,3\}\)/\\.\1/g' file` It finds `.xxx` where `xxx` is 1-3 digits and then replaces the `'.'` with `"\."`. Try it with `echo "file.txt .* 123.123.123.123" | sed 's/[.]\([0-9]\{1,3\}\)/\\.\1/g'`. The result is `"file.txt .* 123\.123\.123\.123"`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin ah yes that works well. Only issue, is that I also need to do the same with the admin bit: `^.*admin\.foo\.com `. Just having a play not to see if I can tweak the regex. I thought this would work but it doesn't: `sed 's/[.]\([a-z0-9A-Z]+\)/\\.\1/g'`

Comment: Oh, okay I see that... That will take a bit more thinking. The hostname  could be any old `host.domain.tld` format?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I guess one option would be to first replace `.*` with `THE_STAR`, then do the `.` regex on the file, and then convert `THE_STAR` back into `.*`. Seems a bit hacky to me though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a little more fiddling we can replace the `'.'` with both digits with word characters and have it work with your example. For instance:

```
sed 's/[.]\(\(\w\w*\)\|\([0-9]\{1,3\}\)\)/\\.\1/g' file
```

Which essentially finds a `'.'` followed by any word character `\w` (at least 1) written as `\w\w*` OR conditionally a `'.'` followed by 1-3 digits `[0-9]\{1,3\}`. Both expressions are captured conditionally in `\(\(words\)\|\(digits\)\)` and then the global replacement made.

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ echo "failregex = ^.*admin.foo.com <HOST> \d+ 213.219.38.44 .*(attacker|scanner|reputation).*" |
sed 's/[.]\(\(\w\w*\)\|\([0-9]\{1,3\}\)\)/\\.\1/g'
failregex = ^.*admin\.foo\.com <HOST> \d+ 213\.219\.38\.44 .*(attacker|scanner|reputation).*
```

Which appears to be what you are looking for.

If you have extended REGEX available, generally through the `-E` (or `-r`) option to `sed`, you can cut down on the escapes in the expression. For example:

```
sed -E 's/[.]((\w+)|([0-9]{1,3}))/\\.\1/g'
```

It works the same, but there were some implementations in the past (I think on Mac) that didn't have ERE available.

Comment: wahooo - thats the beauty! Works liker a charm :) Still feels a bit hacky - but hey ho, it'll do the job

Comment: That's kinds tame, you ought to see some of the hieroglyphics that some of the wizards come up with here `:)` You could get rid of some of the picket-fence look by using extended REGEX, (but then we get into Mac option issues, etc...) Good luck banning the bad guys.

Comment: haha yes I've had my fair share of regexes! I'm more used to it in JS/Perl though, so this was a bit out of my normal area. I'm just trying to write something that will make putting `Maltrail` on all my servers a bit less manual :)

Comment: You will probably like he ERE better `sed -E 's/[.]((\w+)|([0-9]{1,3}))/\\.\1/g'` (note the `-E` option to `sed`, it's `-r` on some)

Comment: ah yes much less clunky / messy without all the escaping ;)